# File Loading Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Well this is a bit of an embarrasing problem, I can't seem to load any sort of file through a program I made. My program fails everytime regardless of the file i try to load, so I'm not quite sure what's going on. Specifically, the program is supposed to be loading GLSL shaders, and it hasn't been working. Here is my code:

```
static inline GLuint GetProgram(const char* vert,const char* frag)
{
GLuint vertex,fragment;
vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

std::string vCode,fCode;
std::ifstream vss(vert);
std::ifstream fss(frag);

if(vss.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(vss,line))
    {
        vCode += line + '\n';
    }
}
else
{
    OutputDebugStringA("ERROR READING VERTEX SHADER\n");
}

if(fss.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(fss,line))
    {
        fCode += line + '\n';
    }
}
else
{
    OutputDebugStringA("ERROR READING FRAGMENT SHADER\n");
}

vss.close();
fss.close();
char const* vsp = vCode.c_str();
char const* fsp = fCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(vertex,1,&vsp,NULL);
glShaderSource(fragment,1,&fsp,NULL);

OutputDebugStringA("Vertex Source:\n");
OutputDebugStringA(vsp + '\n');
OutputDebugStringA("Fragment Source:\n");
OutputDebugStringA(fsp + '\n');

glCompileShader(vertex);
glCompileShader(fragment);

GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShader(prog,vertex);
glAttachShader(prog,fragment);
glLinkProgram(prog);

char errbuf[1024];
GLsizei len;
glGetProgramInfoLog(prog,sizeof(errbuf),&len,errbuf);
OutputDebugStringA(errbuf);

glUseProgram(prog);

return prog;
   }
```

vss.is_open() and fss.is_open() return false everytime. This problem only occurs with this program too, I have another that runs the exact same function listed and it works just fine.

How I am calling it:

```
 GLuint program = Shader::GetProgram("v.vert","f.frag");
```

The directory:

[image]

Comment: check the path to the file.

Comment: The file is in the same directory as the program

Comment: try this: `std::ifstream ifs;  ifs.open (path)`

Comment: if you are running this within visual studio, check ur debug path, it might not be the same as the executable path.

Comment: OK, i tried that to no avail. Thanks for your responses

Comment: @yngum I have tried to run the file from within VS with the debug button and from the release path, they link to the same program

Comment: try to use in the code full path to the file. like d:/work/project/bin/ ...

Comment: @NickEllas you can alawys use [_getcwd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx), concat it with the file name.

Comment: @NickEllas [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197.aspx) will get you the path of the executable.

Comment: Unless you changed the default directory in the settings for the project the default folder in Visual Studio is the same folder the solution file is located in not the folder that the executable is in.

Comment: OK, _getcwd does indeed return a different directory, but im having some issues appending the file name to the dir

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it! Just had to use _getcwd(), move my files to that location and append the file names of the two shaders. Here is my code now:

```
static inline GLuint GetProgram(const char* vert,const char* frag)
{
GLuint vertex,fragment;
vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

const char* dir = _getcwd(NULL,0);
std::string var1 = dir;

std::string vCode,fCode;
std::fstream vss;
std::fstream fss;

char* var2 = "/";

std::string vertpath = var1;
std::string fragpath = var1;
vertpath.append(var2);
fragpath.append(var2);
fragpath.append(frag);
vertpath.append(vert);

vss.open(vertpath);
fss.open(fragpath);
```